# Symfony prod.log exception /var/cache/prod/annotations is not writable

Tags: php, symfony, caching, deployment, permissions

I have web based on symfony 3. For deploy i have own bash script. In this script are routines like git pull, clear cache...

On server is: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

But after deploy i can see exception in `prod.log`:

> [2018-05-11 16:55:36] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "The directory "/var/www/domain.com/var/cache/prod/annotations" is not writable." at /var/www/domain.com/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FileCache.php line 92 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The directory \"/var/www/domain.com/var/cache/prod/annotations\" is not writable. at /var/www/domain.com/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FileCache.php:92)"} []

But problem is - before and after clear cache i have command `chmod -R 777 /var` and after deploy if i look to /var/cache/prod/annotations i see new files with time of change equals time when i run clear cache (via sh script).

Anybody some ideas? Where look what chceck?

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /var` I think that's a terrible idea to change the permissions of the whole `/var` directory. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if your shell writes into `app/cache` first and then you open your website where other parts should be written to that folder too.

Simple solution: add your shell user to the group that your webserver uses, probably `www-data`, through `sudo usermod -a -G www-data userName`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the permissions, to fix use this:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rX folderProject 

setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwX folderProject/var/cache folderProject/var/logs folderProject/var/sessions folderProject/app/sessions  

setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX folderProject/var/cache folderProject/var/logs folderProject/var/sessions folderProject/app/sessions
```

Replace folderProject with your project name.
If you are using Ubuntu with apache this command fix the problem, if you are using another GNU/Linux change the user www-data to your user

Comment: i get `-bash: setfacl: command not found` and /app/sessions does not exist

Comment: What O.S do you use in the server?

Comment: Your project do not have this folder, delete this part of command please and try again

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) is OS and command `setfacl` is not found

Comment: Is very strange, please read this info: https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Default_.28inherited.29_ACL

Comment: Well, if `acl` is not installed, it is not installed. But the solution to add the proper groups is a better one